# Material Components Web - Font size body1 body2 too small on desktop

Tags: css, material-design

Guys the body1 and body2 font size is too small to be the main text size for large desktops.
Any idea how to increase the size consistently all over the css ?

Answer (score 0):

try using vh instead of px for font-size 
maybe try

font-size:6vh;

another option is using media queries - try

```
    @media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    body1 {font-size:32px;}
    }
```

for an example

Comment: I was expecting a SASS macro or something. If  I increase the font I will probably have to scale consistently fonts-height all over, maybe padding and I will have to change all the other fonts size in Material Web Components css.